# Shiny Screenshot without the side bar menu

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyscreenshot

Do you know if it's possible to screenshot all my shiny app without the side bar menu ?

I've tried "selector = #nameofmytabItem" but it don't success.

Here is my actual code :

```
observeEvent(input$screenshot, {
    screenshot(
      selector = "#Radar_Moyennes2"
    )
```

Comment: It's about shinydashboard::sidebarMenu

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyscreenshot)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
               badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green"),
      actionButton("screenshot", "Take screenshot")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Dashboard tab content")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$screenshot, {
    shinyjs::addCssClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    screenshot(
      # selector = "body > div > div > section"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working there is'nt the sidebarmenu in the screenshot but the rest of the application is cut on the left side :(

Comment: The right side I guess?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to only blank out the sidebar: `CSS selector for the element that should be captured. If multiple elements match the selector, only the first one is captured. Default is to capture the entire page.` From `?screenshot`.

Comment: No the left side..

Comment: Ok...Thank's a lot for your help!

Comment: Maybe we could programmatically collapse the sidebar before taking a screenshot of the whole page. Is that an option?

Comment: @Elise_351995 please check my edit.

Comment: Yes it is an option, but the ideal would be that users do not have to do anything to have a perfect screenshot

Comment: @Elise_351995 Please check my edited code above - the user doesn't have to do something - the sidebar is collapsed *programmatically*  before taking the screenshot.

Comment: @Elise_351995 did you check my updated code?

Comment: @ismirsehregal, was searching for hours a way to make it work, your code finally solved my issue. Thank you so much, *upvote*. (und schade, dass der Eröffner nicht mal Rückmeldung gibt... Danke nochmals!)

Answer (score 0):

By taking a chunk of @ismirsehregal code, if you want to just screenshot the dashboardBody feature then the following code should work.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyscreenshot)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
               badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green"),
      actionButton("screenshot", "Take screenshot")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Dashboard tab content")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$screenshot, {
    shinyjs::addCssClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    screenshot(
      selector = "body > div > div > section"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```